# Segue to random Index using Pull to Refresh?

Tags: ios, swift, indexing, uicollectionview, refresh

I've set up a `UIRefreshControl` on my CollectionView using this code

```
let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.refreshLoad), for: .valueChanged)
    collectionViewIBO.addSubview(refreshControl)
```

What I'm stumped on is how to segue using the refresh. Currently I use `didSelectItemAt` with my model `datasource.model[indexPath.row]` to segue. I want to be able to select a random index to segue to inside this function

```
func refreshLoad() {

    print("refresh")
    self.collectionViewIBO.reloadData()


    stopRefresher()
}
```

I know to get the random Index I use `Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(model.count)))`. But how would I call this function to perform the same action as `didSelectItemAt`?

Comment: What does your `didSelectItemAt` look like?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the same behaviour. Why not create a seperate function that takes an indexPath as an argument.

Call it someting like:

```
segueToUsing(indexPath : NSIndexPath) {
    // Your current didSelectRowAt implementation
}
```

Then in your didSelectRowAt simply call this function with the given indexPath. And in your `refreshLoad` function call this `segueToUsing` function with a generated random indexPath:

```
let row = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(model.count)))
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(row: row, section: 1)
```

This will solve both with 1 implementation.